# How i can definy the limit between polymorphism and override method?

Tags: java, oop, overriding

I'm studying OOP in Java, and i already understand the concepts about polymorphism and @override methods, but how one can be used without another?

I would like to understand if there is an occasion of using polymorphism in which method overwriting is not used.

Comment: If there is such an occasion it is very rare. Overriding methods goes hand in hand with polymorphism.

Comment: Polymorphism can only be achieved when there is inheritance accompanied by overriding. Overriding is all about bringing a change and without change how can one achieve Poly-Morphism (multiple forms/outcomes during multiple instance)

Comment: Subclassing can be augmentation w/o overrides, e.g., a base class provides common functionality, and subclasses extend/use that functionality without replacing it. This isn't as unusual as the preceding comments imply *(for better or worse)*. *(Whether or not subclassing is the **best** approach, then, is a separate conversation, e.g., composition may make more sense.)*

Comment: Polymorphism is a broader concept than subclassing/overriding. Overloading, for example, also is a form of Polymorphism. Generics too.

Answer (score -1):

Overriding is only required if you're extending an `abstract` class which contains `abstract` methods, or implementing an `interface` which contains un-implemented methods.

For example, the `Object` class, which all Java classes inherently extend, includes methods that can optionally be overridden, such as `toString`.

Consider the following `abstract class`.

```java
abstract class Example {
    String stringA = "stack";
    String stringB = "overflow";

    private String methodA() {
        return stringA + " " + stringB;
    }

    protected int methodB(int value) {
        return value + 100;
    }

    public abstract int methodC(int valueA, int valueB);
}
```

`methodA` cannot be overridden; it is marked as `private`.
`methodB` can optionally be overridden, although it is not required.
`methodC` requires an implementation, thus is overridable.

Interfaces are similar.

```java
interface Example {
    String stringA = "stack";
    String stringB = "overflow";

    private String methodA() {
        return stringA + " " + stringB;
    }

    default int methodB(int value) {
        return value + 100;
    }

    int methodC(int valueA, int valueB);
}
```

`methodA` cannot be overridden; it is marked as `private`.
`methodB` can optionally be overridden, although it is not required.
`methodC` requires an implementation, thus is overridable.

For more information on this topic, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html.

As a way to demonstrate the polymorphism of the `interface`, consider the following two implementing classes.

```java
class ExampleImplA implements Example {
    @Override
    public int methodC(int valueA, int valueB) {
        return valueA * valueB;
    }
}

class ExampleImplB implements Example {
    @Override
    public int methodC(int valueA, int valueB) {
        return valueA - valueB;
    }
}
```

Now, from another class, if you created a list of `Example`'s, supplying a different implementation for each item, if you called `methodC` on each of the list items, a different implementation of `methodC` will be executed.

```java
void method() {
    List<Example> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ExampleImplA());
    list.add(new ExampleImplB());
    for (Example example : list)
        example.methodC(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked in any way.

Comment: In what way?  I've defined the difference between using polymorphism with and without overriding methods.  If anything, that is the exact answer.

Comment: So, how can i apply the polymorphism in methods B and C ?, polimorphism means many forms to call a method, but if the method cant be override, how can i apply ?

Comment: The polymorphism of `methodB` would be that, depending on the implementing class, and whether or not that class chose to override the method, a different implementation may or may not be executed.  And, the polymorphism of `methodC` would be that no matter what class is calling the method, the same code is executed.  This is in terms of "overriding", which is different from "overloading".

Comment: @ArthurBittencourt I updated my answer to provide some clarity.

Comment: @ArthurBittencourt, your initial question is, "how can one be used without the other".  You don't need to override the method to consider it polymorphic.  What makes it polymorphism is that the implementing class that is accessing the method is different from another.  So, it is multiple objects utilizing a single method, which may or may not be overridden.  So, "poly" meaning many, and "morphic" meaning ability-to-change.

Comment: Additionally, you're saying that if the method can't be overridden, then how is it polymorphism.  The "poly" part is in reference to the multiple classes that can implement it, and not the method.  The "morphism" part is in reference to the method, which has the ability to change.